# How can I target an element that is in an iFrame within another iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to target an element inside of an iFrame that is within another iFrame. Is it possible?

```html
<iframe src="parent.html" id="parentFrame">

    <iframe src="child.html" id="childFrame">
        <!-- <div id="target-element"><div> -->
    </iframe>

</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the content of the two iframes hosted on the same domain? If so, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/519413)

Comment: Yes, same domain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<iframe src="frame1.html"></iframe>
```

In frame1.html you can do:

```
<iframe src="frame2.html"></iframe>
```

Then in frame2.html you can put the Div:

```
<div class="target"><!-- content here --></div>
```

The javascript will be as follows:
`function getDiv() { return document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('.target'); }`
Then use `getDiv()` to get the div you want to get.